# What is the workflow for using and backing up encrypted remote fossil repositories?

Tags: encryption, fossil

Fossil has support for encrypted repositories (https://fossil-scm.org/home/doc/trunk/www/encryptedrepos.wiki) using the SQLite Encryption Extension. I have made a build of fossil using the open source SQLCipher SEE extension (https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher) to play around with it.

As noted in the documentation each fossil command asks the user for the passphrase to decrypt the underlying sqlite database before performing the vcs functions.

- If there is a central repository Bob and Alice are committing to in order to share changes is it possible to prompt them for the passphrase via SSH or must you run the http/scgi server so the passphrase is stored in memory?
- The recommended way of backing up a fossil repo is done by running something like `fossil sql "vacuum repository into repo.backup"` that way an uncommitted transaction doesn't copied (if you use plain `cp`). Is there a way to make a complete backup of the encrypted repository without having to type the passphrase so it can be automated with something like cron?

Comment: It would be worth asking (copy/pasting) this question on the Fossil forums: https://fossil-scm.org/forum/forummain (you don't need to register to post).
In other news (not that it helps with the password prompting thing), a new 'backup' function has just been added (which basically just runs the command you said). I have a feeling that for cron, you might need to call on a keychain/password manager from the bash script/cron job that calls Fossil.

Comment: Ah yeah, a password manager might be the way to go for this case. I didn't think of that. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: https://fossil-scm.org/forum/forumpost/ba4d0418f1  cross reference